# Sylvester-like criterion for semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

In Zhou's [A Practical Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1438236662) I see the following:

> A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite  if and only if all its upper left (or lower right) submatrices have nonnegative determinants.

I know that looking only at upper left submatrices (i.e, leading principal minors) is not enough to guarantee semidefinitess (see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3560719)).

I'm confused by Zhou's wording. I think it should read "all its upper left **and lower right** submatrices have nonnegative determinants". Is this a correct statement for semidefiniteness ?
I'm not good enough at linear algebra to come up with a proof.

Comment: *'I think it should read "all its upper left and lower right submatrices have nonnegative determinants". Is this a correct statement for semidefiniteness ?'*  No.  The correct statement of Sylvester's generalized criterion for semi-definiteness (for real symmetric or hermitian matrixes) is that *all principal minors are* $\geq 0$.  I gave a proof here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145638/a-is-positive-semidefinite-iff-textdet-b-k-geq-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. As a simple counterexample, consider the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0}.
$$
It should be clear that all "leading" and "trailing" principal minors are zero and therefore non-negative. However, this matrix fails to be positive semidefinite.

For an arguably more interesting example, you can consider
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&2\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
2&1&1&1
}.
$$

Comment: Nice counterexample !